# Як перекласти follow-up letter?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Часто після ділової зустрічі приходиться писати лист з ключовими моментами зустрічі. Такий собі лист-резюме. Англійською це називають follow-up letter. 
Я не можу підібрати український аналог, який би не звучав як варіант від Google Translate(тупо і в лоб).
Як перекласти на українську "follow-up letter"?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Цей сайт — не перекладацький сервіс. Для того, щоб на запитання можна було відповісти, треба (1) написати своїми словами значення іноземного слова, про яке йдеться; (2) уточнити контекст, в якому слово має виживатися; (3) показати спробу розв'язати проблему самостійно; (4) пояснити, чим знайдені в Інтернеті варіанти перекладу не підходять до вашої мети.

Comment: *Лист нагадування* (можна з дефісом) або *лист в нагадування*, *лист продовження* (можна з дефісом) або *лист в продовження*, *перевіряльний лист*, *контрольний лист*. Також дивись [follow-up](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=follow-up&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Comment: А чому вам *резюме зустрічі* не подобається?

Answer (score 5):

**`Подальший лист`** або **`лист із (щодо) подальших кроків`**

Принаймні, такий варіант перекладу і вживання ***`follow-up`*** знаходимо в документах:

1. [Підсумковий документ](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/994_113) Віденської зустрічі 1986 року представників  держав-учасниць  Наради  з питань безпеки і співробітництва в Європі, що відбулася на  основі  положень Підсумкового  акта, які відносяться до ***подальших кроків*** після наради (Concluding Document of Vienna Meeting 1986 of Representatives 
   of the Participating States of  the  Conference  on  Security  and Co-operation in Europe, Held on the Basis of the Provisions of the Final Act Relating to the ***Follow-up*** to  the  Conference)
2. [Глосарій Європейського простору вищої освіти (ЄПВО)](http://lpehea.in.ua/sites/default/files/documents/2014/09/22/glossary_9.pdf)  - EUROPEAN STANDARDS/ЄВРОПЕЙСЬКІ
   СТАНДАРТИ - ... ***follow-up procedures*** - ***подальші процедури***/...
3. [Матеріали семінару "Підтримка розвитку громади зсередини"](http://www.uiip.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/UIIP_UCBI-Handouts.pdf) проекту UCBI/USAID - ***Follow-up проекту*** - ***подальший розвиток***

Додатково, стаття в СУМ на слово [ПОДА́ЛЬШИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/podaljshyj), а, е.

> 1. **Який настає, іде, відбувається і т. ін. після чого-небудь, за чимсь; протилежне попередній.** Контузія і нелегке подальше життя
>      наклали свій відбиток на характер і душевний склад хлопця (Іван Цюпа,
>      Вічний вогонь, 1960, 132); Знали, нелегкою буде подальша дорога (Олесь
>      Гончар, II, 1959, 128);
>
> //  **Який триває далі, продовжується (про розвиток, прогрес і т.
>   ін.)**. Лірична тема батьківщини, її людей і пейзажу знайшла подальший
>   розвиток у творчості художників-реалістів (Літературна Україна, 27.III
>   1964, 4).

Comment: Із вашого першого прикладу випливає також *«підсумковий лист»*, який особисто мені дуже подобається, навіть якщо це і новотвір.

Comment: @bytebuster, в першому прикладі *підсумковий* відповідає англійським *concluding* і *final* (і це, я так розумію, офіційний переклад). Якщо його ще вживати для *follow-up*, буде плутанина, особливо в офіційних документах.